# SSL Connection from Java client

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, https

I'm creating a Java client program that will be sending sensitive information to a Tomcat server.  So I need to use SSL Connection so information will be encrypted.

I need to use self-signed untrusted certificate but having problems making connection from java client.

I have successfully setup Tomcat 5.5 to use SSL and tested it through Firefox, which displays warning of self-signed certificate.

I followed the Tomcat 5.5 SSL setup and they mentioned to create a keystore:

> `keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA`

Then I did an export of the above:

> `keytool -export -keystore .keystore -alias tomcat -file localhost.cer`

Then I did an import of the above certificate into client machine:

> `keytool -import -alias tomcat -file localhost.cer -keystore "C:\Program Files"\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\jre\lib\security\cacerts"`

But when running client I get:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

This is the client code:

```
URL url = new URL("https://localhost:8443");
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
conn.setSSLSocketFactory(sslsocketfactory);
InputStream inputstream = conn.getInputStream();
```

Now I just started playing with these certificates today and I'm new to keystores, so please be patient.

Can someone please explain how to export and import the certificate created in Tomcat to client machine?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you imported the wrong certificate, or maybe you imported it into the wrong JRE. Lots of folks have multiple JRE's on their machines. You should list the contents of cacerts and see if your cert is in there. Also, you can set the system property java.net.debug=all to see what much more detail about the certificate sending and checking parts.

Answer (score 1):

Atlassian has good instructions on how to fix this.

http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Connecting+to+SSL+services

Another approach is to install less unforgiving certificate validators, but that should only be done as a last resort.

Comment: If I disable SSL certification validation altogether will the data sent to server still be encrypted?
I found an example that does not validate SSL certs but want to make sure if the transmission of data will still be encrypted.

Comment: If you disable SSL validation the SSL tunnel will still exist and the data will still be encrypted.  **BUT** you will no longer know where that tunnel is terminated!  An attacker could do something like this to break your security: poison your DNS with an arbitrary IP address, generate a self-signed SSL cert for the FQDN you are connecting, listen for SSL on poison IP address and respond with fake SSL cert.  Without validation your SSL client will trust the server's SSL cert, regardless of the CA it came from.

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache [HTTP Cleint](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) jar and follow this [SSL Guide](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/sslguide.html).

[EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpcomponents/oac.hc3x/trunk/src/contrib/org/apache/commons/httpclient/contrib/ssl/EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory.java?view=markup)  can be used to create SSL connections that allow the target server to authenticate with a self-signed certificate.

Comment: Can the person who marked negative explain why so? I have used this solution and it works very fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should input password using "changeit".